# From axis values to coodinates pairs

Tags: r, coordinates, spatial, points

I have axis values in two variables. E.g.  `x = c(10,15); y=c(30,35,40)` and I need to build a spatial points for representing these intersections of axis lines, as can be seen in this image.
[image: Coordinates and points]

I need to build a spatial point dataframe from x and y variables that should look like this:

```
x   y
10  30
15  30
10  35
15  35
10  40
15  40
```

How should I code this order in R?

Comment: See `?expand.grid`. So `expand.grid(x = c(10,15), y = c(30,35,40))`.

Comment: Yes! This is the solution.
Sorry, I could not find with different sizes of x and y vectors.
Thank you!

Comment: No need to apologize, I just linked this to the other question since there is no need for people to answer it again. Your picture actually nicely illustrates why this function is called `expand.grid`!